# Can not download file from OneDrive using "source" or Rest API url (404 error)

Tags: ios, rest, onedrive

I am trying to get the content of file store on OneDrive from the REST API.
I access to the list of my files with the iOS SDK (https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-iOS).
I get all the information from the object that I want to download. So I assume that all the login process are ok and I can get the accessToken from the current session.

This is my session scopes:

```
   scopes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      @"wl.signin",
                      @"wl.basic",
                      @"wl.skydrive",
                      @"wl.offline_access", nil];
```

I have the "wl.skydrive" that it is a "preresquisite".

From the file that I want to download I got this information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631831.aspx

The documentation say that the "source" object contains a temporal URL where I can download the file. But inmediatly I try to make the get from that source URL but I receive a 404 http response (my URL looks very similar to example URL so should be fine).

Here is the response

```
url called: https://cr2vng.bn1302.livefilestore.com/y2mOPOvT5FDRrIRdKbCS3xtwQH9zz2gzzYPxLHIcOpHSo6bKP3QqJpGpL1U9c76a_QCwFwEPyTEbF2CVU63tb92bOkQ9ahcxAOhSBPws21K7DL5TnNe3AmbHThv4zlbohKiB8x6JO9gE2gjUcOUImPImA/01%20-%File%Name.mp3?psid=1
2015-03-24 21:55:20.339[1435:149631] response: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7ff36af04ed0> { URL: https://cr2vng.bn1302.livefilestore.com/y2mOPOvT5FDRrIRdKbCS3xtwQH9zz2gzzYPxLHIcOpHSo6bKP3QqJpGpL1U9c76a_QCwFwEPyTEbF2CVU63tb92bOkQ9ahcxAOhSBPws21K7DL5TnNe3AmbHThv4zlbohKiB8x6JO9gE2gjUcOUImPImA/01%20-%File%Name.mp3?psid=1 } { status code: 404, headers {
"Accept-Ranges" = bytes;
"Content-Encoding" = gzip;
"Content-Length" = 0;
Date = "Tue, 24 Mar 2015 20:55:19 GMT";
P3P = "CP=\"BUS CUR CONo FIN IVDo ONL OUR PHY SAMo TELo\"";
Server = "Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0";
"X-AsmVersion" = "UNKNOWN; 19.16.0.0";
"X-ClientErrorCode" = ItemDoesNotExist;
"X-MSNSERVER" = "BN1302____PAP221";
"X-QosStats" = "{\"ApiId\":0,\"ResultType\":2,\"SourcePropertyId\":0,\"TargetPropertyId\":42}";
"X-ThrowSite" = "4359.b800";
} }
```

I also tried to do the same request using the REST API (https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn659726.aspx#Download_a_file) with identical result. Using that API call I finally got a redirection to a similar URL that I got on the "source" object.

The 404 in both cases do not have sense because I am getting on that exact moment the "id" from the object that exist.

Can I have something wrong on my App configuration on the OneDrive developer account?

Answer (score 0):

It is strange, all my files disappear from OneDrive and after upload them again I can access to the files without any problem using the URL that I got on "source".

I did not made any change on the code